# How to list the used chars in a text in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, duplicates

I would like to list the chars used in a string (sorted) with a function like this one :

```
def foobar(string):
    return ????

string = 'what a nice day'
print foobar(string)
```

This should print the string `acdehintwy`

What would be the foobar() function?

I tried OrderedDict.fromkeys(items) but I can't sort it afterwards...

Comment: Spaces are excluded - should punctuation be? What about capital letters? `sorted(OrderedDict...)` works fine for me; could you describe the problem more precisely, and provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s='what a nice day'

print ("".join(set(s.replace(" ",""))))
acedihntwy
```

A  [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) will remove the duplicates and `s.replace(" ","")` will remove the spaces

```
def foobar(s):
    return "".join(set(s.replace(" ","")))

In [4]: foobar("what a nice day")
Out[4]: 'acedihntwy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

```
>>> mystring = 'what a nice day'
>>> chars = sorted(set(mystring.replace(" ", "")))
>>> print(chars)
['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'n', 't', 'w', 'y']
>>> "".join(chars)
'acdehintwy'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nearly what I'm looking for. How can I get a string from that? I tried join() but it doesn't work on a set

Comment: @FlipFlapFlop `str.join` **does** work on a `set` (of `str`s).

Answer (score 0):

with set and list comprehension to get rid of the space :

```
"".join([i for i in set(string) if i!=' '])
acedihntwy
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort a string by characters, you can use the `sorted` builtin. It returns a list of individual characters you can then put together with `string.join`. Because it seems that you want each character to only appear once, filter out duplicates by using `set`:

```
def foobar(string):
    return "".join(sorted(set(string)))
```

This results in

```
>>> foobar("what a nice day")
" acdehintwy"
```